# how to find all *.pdf from my local ubuntu machine in angular 2 ionic framework?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

how to find all *.pdf from my local ubuntu machine in angular 2 ionic framework?

In linux we can achieve by below command:

```
find / -iname *.pdf
```

Please describe in details since i am not familiar with ionic.

Any help appreciate. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

**PS: Oh sorry I didnt notice that you were talking about Ionic, in this case, you can access the phone device using the File Api: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/**

You just can't !!! Imagine if anyone can do this by navigating to his website/mobile app and getting all your indiscreet *.jpg files :D

Explanation: Angular is a front-end framework, so the code is executed in the client side, if you are able to do this in your local machine, then when you deploy the app, you will be able to access all the *.pdf files of your visitors. That's why it's impossible !

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have one question...there is a app which will show duplicates images in your galary. How that possible? I think it's possible if user give a permissions to app to allow images/pdfs etc. I just want to find all paths where pdfs/images are saved. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Yes you can, you have to use the Ionic File API, I updated my answer with a link to it

Comment: hi, i am getting error "ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError
TypeError
    at window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL"

my code -->
this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      file.listDir(this.file.externalDataDirectory,'').then((result)=>{
                        console.log(result);})
    });

Comment: Have you installed the File plugins ? As mentioned in the doc: 

$ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file
$ npm install --save @ionic-native/file

Comment: yes, i installed $ ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-file $ npm install --save @ionic-native/file